# Forms - synchronous request and displaying a div on submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a yahtzee-type two player dice game. To start the game, the user enters 2 names and submits, which should start the game and display the dice area. I've done a lot of trial and error, but I haven't been able to submit the form, get the input, and show the play area.

HTML:

```
    <div id="top_area">
    <div id="new_game_form">
        <form action="http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php" method="post" name="new_game">
            Player 1:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="player1">
            <br> Player 2:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="player2">
            <br>
            <input id="newGameSubmit" type="submit" value="Start Game">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="player_turn">
        Please enter player names and load a new game!
    </div>
    <div id="player_scores">
        Current Score
    </div>
</div>
<div id="play_area">
    <div class="play_div" id="game_board">
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice1"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice2"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice3"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice4"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice5"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="play_div" id="submit_move">
        <form class="play_div" action="http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php" method="post" name="submit_move">
            <input type="submit" value="Roll the dice!" onclick="rollDice()">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="submit_score">
        <form action="">
            <select name="Score">
                <option value="2OfAKind">Two of a kind</option>
                <option value="3OfAKind">Three of a kind</option>
                <option value="4OfAKind">Four of a kind</option>
                <option value="5OfAKind">Five of a kind</option>
                <option value="fullHouse">Full house</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit your score">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //game setup
    $("#new_game").on("submit", newGameListener);
});


function newGameListener(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUpUsers();
    $(".play_area").show(); 
}
```

I've also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#new_game").submit(function (event) {

        var newGameData = {
            "player1": $("input[name=player1]").val(),
            "player2": $("input[name=player2]").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php",
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                encode: true
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                (".play_area").show();
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newGameSubmit").click(function () {

            event.preventDefault();

            var player1 = $("#player1").val();
            var player2 = $("#player2").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    (".play_area").show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
   });
});
```

I suspect my usage of form name may be wrong (should I be using id instead? is the # right? etc.) but I've played around with that and still couldn't get it.

Comment: Are any errors being thrown or reported? Check the "Console" and "Network" in your browser's developer tools. Note that `$.ajax()` errors are silently discarded unless you provide a listener for them – via `error` option or [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried modifying your last approach. I hope it will work once you update it with below modified code:

In your HTML; `play_area` is an `id` given to `<div>` element. So to deal with it JQuery we need to use `#` and not the dot. Like `$("#play_area").show();`

**CSS:**

```
#play_area{
  display:none;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("form[name=new_game]").submit(function (e) {
         return false;
    });

    $("#newGameSubmit").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var player1 = $("#player1").val();
      var player2 = $("#player2").val();

      var newGameData = {
        "player1": player1,
        "player2": player2
      };

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php",
        data: newGameData,
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
          $("#play_area").show();
        }
      });
   });
});
```

I have created a fiddle too; but it won't work because we can't make cross domain Ajax calls from within `jsfiddle.net` to your `funwebdev.com` domain.
But you can refer it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vijayP/bkvw95jn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the form not being submitted. Check the following code.. !!

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#new_game").submit(function() {
            var newGameData = {
                "player1": $("input[name=player1]").val(),  
                "player2": $("input[name=player2]").val()
            };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php",
                    data: newGameData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    encode: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                       (".play_area").show();
                        alert(data); 
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top_area">
    <div id="new_game_form">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="new_game" name="new_game">
            Player 1:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="player1">
            <br> Player 2:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="player2">
            <br>
            <input id="newGameSubmit" type="submit" value="Start Game">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="player_turn">
        Please enter player names and load a new game!
    </div>
    <div id="player_scores">
        Current Score
    </div>
</div>
<div id="play_area">
    <div class="play_div" id="game_board">
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice1"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice2"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice3"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice4"></a>
        <a class="diceimage" id="dice5"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="play_div" id="submit_move">
        <form class="play_div" action="http://examples.funwebdev.com/process.php" method="post" name="submit_move">
            <input type="submit" value="Roll the dice!" onclick="rollDice()">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="submit_score">
        <form action="">
            <select name="Score">
                <option value="2OfAKind">Two of a kind</option>
                <option value="3OfAKind">Three of a kind</option>
                <option value="4OfAKind">Four of a kind</option>
                <option value="5OfAKind">Five of a kind</option>
                <option value="fullHouse">Full house</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit your score">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```